# Check if match group exists without 'try'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.8 and regular expressions, is there a way to see if match group 2 exists without having to catch an exception? 'not None' doesn't get evaluated and I get a 'no such group' error before that.

The function is supposed to pick apart email From addresses that look like '"Real Name" foo.bar@example.com'. If there is a real name I would like to get that if not I would do some further checking.

```
def cleanmystuff(stuff): # removes tabs, spaces, newlines, quotes, returns something
    regex = r"(.*\S).*<(.*)>"
    stuff = stuff.replace('"', ' ')
    stuff = stuff.replace(',', ' ')
    a_list = stuff.split()
    allthestuff = " ".join(a_list)
    matches = re.match(regex, allthestuff)
    if matches.group(2) is not None:
        return matches.group(2)
    # code may go on
```

Comment: You just need `if matches` - all groups either exist or they don't

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this was useful to me in the context of named groups where I don't even know which regexp (from a list of regular expressions) was executed. All I know is the name of the group. I'll try to demonstrate a couple of solutions below:

With unnamed groups:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'(foo)?(bar)?', 'foo')
>>> match and match.groups()[1]
None
>>> match = re.search(r'(foo)?(bar)?', 'foobar')
>>> match and match.groups()[1]
'bar'
```

With named groups:

```
>>> match = re.search(r'(?P<foo>foo)?(?P<bar>bar)?', 'foo')
>>> match and match.groupdict().get('bar')
None
>>> match = re.search(r'(?P<foo>foo)?(?P<bar>bar)?', 'foobar')
>>> match and match.groupdict().get('bar')
'bar'
```

Your example:

```
def cleanmystuff(stuff):
    regex = r"(.*\S).*<(.*)>"
    stuff = stuff.replace('"', ' ')
    stuff = stuff.replace(',', ' ')
    a_list = stuff.split()
    allthestuff = " ".join(a_list)
    matches = re.match(regex, allthestuff)
    if matches and matches.group(2) is not None:
        return matches.group(2)
```

Comment: I believe all named groups in the pattern are present in the group dict (with a value of `None` if not matched), so in the named group example `groupdict().get("bar")` could be `groupdict()["bar"]`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Python 3.8, why not just use the [new walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)? This use-case is one of the [official examples](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) for this new feature:

```py
if (match := re.match(regex, allthestuff)) is not None:
    return match.group(2)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understand this correctly it checks if there was a match (any) and then returns what is in group 2. I would like to know if group 2 has a match. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I noticed that the question and the example didn't match up. Sorry about that. I would like to know if there is a match in group 2.

Comment: There will be *something* there (even if it is just an empty string) if `match` itself is not `None`. The regular expression as a whole either matches or doesn't.

Comment: The only way `groups(x)` returns `None` is if your regular expression is something like `r1|r2`, where `r2` matches but has fewer capture groups than `r1`.

Comment: @chepner I think another possible way is if you have something like `r1(r2)?` where `r2` is optional so in cases that it was matched without, it will be `None`

Answer (score 4):

You must use the following code:

```
if re.match(regex, content) is not None:
    ...
```

**string_to_evaluate** = *"Your text that needs to be examined"*

**expected_pattern** = *"pattern"*

use this:

```
if re.match(expected_pattern, string_to_evaluate) is not None:
    print("The text is as you expected!")
else:
    print("The text is not as you expected!")
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the question and the example didn't match up. Sorry about that. I would like to know if there is a match in group 2 not if there was a match at all.

Comment: You make a list of groups and then check if they match